# create users to site with specific language

Tags: wp-admin, users, user-roles, plugin-polylang

We've created a website that has 8 languages, Russian, Spanish or English to name a few. Each language has its own version of the website.

I'm trying to create users that will be able to only modify the site's assigned languages.

For example, if I create a user for the Russian version, that person will be only able to modify the Russian version.

The webdesigner who created the website said it cannot be done but I'm still asking, just in case.

For info, I'm using the module `polylang`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually a plugin that offers this exact functionality: [Polylang User Manager](http://wooexperts.com/plugins/polylang-user-manager/):

> Polylang User Manager will work with Polylang WordPress multilingual Plugin, it will allow you to restrict access for editors/shop_manager or other user role based on languages they’re not assigned as Translators or editor.

Comment: Looks like a really good fit for someone willing to shell out 50$ to have something that works without tinkering.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I haven't used this, but from the description it looks like a good fit.

---

The [groups plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/groups/) says it allows you to restrict an user's access to posts, so you could create one group per language, and assign each user to a group, then restrict users to only be able to edit posts of their group.

The language info might be duplicated between polylang and groups, but it would probably work.

If this doesn't work, leave a comment, I'll delete (or edit) the post.

Comment: Doesn't polylang save all languages in the same post via shortcodes?

Comment: @kero I dunno, I actually haven't used either, this post is just duckduck-fu.

Comment: No, polylang duplicates the original post, so in theory you could add a user meta field to the users and then filter the posts/pages in the back-end.You could have a look at the plugin "restrict categories" (https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-categories/) to get an idea on how to filter the posts in the back-end based on a condition.